# What HTTP Request Method to use when addressing a service?

Tags: web-services, http, w3c, http-method

I've built an API which basically forwards HTTP-Requests to a service of mine. The service calls an internal function and sends the answer back.
Both, request and answer, have a body with information.
The problem is that i dont now which HTTP Method i should use, since none of the descriptions really fit my case. Especially because i, strictly speaking, don't have a resource, but rather a service.

The API is already working, i temporarily used POST since it was the closest, but none the less it doesn't really fit completely.

Comment: There aren't many choices, and POST is probably most appropriate, but in what ways does POST not fit your service?

Comment: @Alohci According to the POST docu by W3C The POST "method is used to request that the origin server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line." However i dont create i subordinate or whatsoever of any kind. Im just calling a function on my local Service